# stunnel https gets redirected to http

Tags: linux, mono, servicestack, stunnel

I have a Web service listening on port 8081 (it's a ServiceStack REST Web Service running on mono, if that helps). I am trying to secure it using stunnel, but the problem is as soon as I connect to https://ip, it gets redirected to http://ip:8081, which doesn't make sense to me.
Could somebody point me in a direction? My stunnel config file follows:

```
cert = stunnel.pem

chroot = /usr/local/var/run/stunnel/
pid = /stunnel.pid

setuid = nobody
setgid = nobody

foreground = yes

[https] 
accept = 443 
connect = 8081
```

Answer (score 1):

Your stunnel config works for me.

It sounds like your webserver is likely sending a 403 redirect, which you do not want.